# Convert string to lambda expression that contains variables from other classes

Tags: c#, string, parsing, lambda, linq-expressions

What I've been trying to do is convert a **string** of the form:

```
"StudentDatabase.avgHeight > 1.7"
```

to a **lambda expression** that looks like this:

```
() => StudentDatabase.avgHeight > 1.7;
```

I tried something in the lines of this:

```
/* String splitting and parsing occurs here */ 
var comparison = Expression.GreaterThan(
    Type.GetType("MyNamespace.StudentDatabase").GetField("avgHeight"),
    Expression.Constant(1.7)
);                

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(comparison).Compile();
```

Of course something like this **wouldn't work** since the *GetField()* method returns type *FieldInfo* and not *Expression*.

Here's a list about useful stuff you might want to know about my sample code:

- The *StudentDatabase* class is a static class that contains a static field *avgHeight*.
- I have already done the part of the code that parses the string so there's no need to include it in any provided solutions.
- This is just an example so you can change the string and variable/class names if you wish so.

This is **not** an assignment so feel free to post source code. In fact, that would be greately appreciated.

**TL;DR;** What I'm trying to do is use **LINQ Expressions** to **access variables** from other places of the code.

Comment: LINQ is primarily used for `IEnumerable` querying. It doesn't seem like LINQ is the solution you need. I think you just need to change around the way your expression parsing works.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I am inexperienced with LINQ and I recognize that it might have not been the solution. I am aware that the code is unsafe but thats perfectly allright for the project that I'm gonna use it for. If you have any other suggestions on how to "Convert string to lamda expression that contains variables from other classes" even without using LINQ that would be apprieciated. ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the following comments, Linq expressions is a viable way to do this sort of thing. The below code accomplishes it. However, please consider the following code:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* String splitting and parsing occurs here */

            var comparison = Expression.GreaterThan(
                Expression.Field(null, Type.GetType("MyNamespace.StudentDatabase").GetField("avgHeight")),
                Expression.Constant(1.7)
            );

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(comparison).Compile();
            StudentDatabase.avgHeight = 1.3;
            var result1 = lambda(); //is true
            StudentDatabase.avgHeight = 2.0;
            var result2 = lambda(); //is false
        }
    }

    class StudentDatabase
    {
        public static double avgHeight = 1.3;
    }

}
```

Should `result2` be true or false? If you want it to be true, then you have more work to do.

Comment: That's the answer! Had no idea something like Expression.Field() existed.
I tried your code and it works just as I wanted to, thanks a lot for the reply. 
(You mixed up the results , result1 is false and result2 is true so it works just fine)
I'm marking this as the answer. Again, thank you for your time and providing an answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

I've created this as a sort of framework you can work off of. It does not use LINQ but will output the value specified by the string.

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.StudentDatabase");
if (type != null)
{
    var field = type.GetField("avgHeight");
    if (field != null)
    {
        Func<bool> lambda = () => (double)field.GetValue(type) > 1.7;   
    }
}
```

There is some error checking you could add/remove. The other areas such as the `>` and `1.7` can be parsed elsewhere and inserted but this is how you could get a value from the strings.

Comment: Also if you need the `lambda` variable outside of the inner scope you could create a default expression outside the scope of the `if` statements then overwrite it after the error checking.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I might be wrong here so please correct me if so, but what would happen if I added the lambda expression to a list and then entered a second string afterwards? 
Wouldn't the field variable be overwritten and change the first lambda function too?
So the above code would only work if I had a list of all fields available and used an index inside each lambda function.?

Comment: So your question made it seem like there would only be 1 class string and 1 field string to get. If your string was something like `StudentDatabase.students.heights.avgHeights` then you would need to break that up into a list. Then traverse the list (preferably null checking each time) then once you've checked if `avgHeights` is a field of `heights` you could get the value of it. You may need to use a method other than `GetField` while traversing however. Did that at least kind-of answer your question?

Comment: Well I do not want to seem like a picky person or anything, but I have to ask what to you mean "the > and 1.7 can be parsed elswewhere and **inserted**"? I know how to get the value from strings, I just do not know how to make it work while converting it into a lambda expression.
It's a really important aspect of my problem as the question is "how to parse a string into a lambda expression". If that is replied and I manage to make it work I would more than willingly mark this as an answer. 
Thank you for spending your time, tho. I appreciate it.